# Java, remove text and the line break in a stringBuffer

Tags: java, line-breaks, stringbuffer

i have this text coming in to a string buffer,

```
857,9/25/14
REEL SCAN,BASIS WT
,0.7600,66067.3,50212.4,61.0
,49.572,-0.3720,0.0000
,111.89,108.28,94.72,106.23
,99.82,83.41
```

after running this

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    line = line.replace("REEL SCAN" + "," + "BASIS WT", "");
                    stringBuffer.append(line.trim());
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
```

i get this

```
857,9/25/14

,0.7600,66067.3,50212.4,61.0
,49.572,-0.3720,0.0000
,111.89,108.28,94.72,106.23
,99.82,83.41
```

how do i get rid of the blank line at the same time to make this

```
857,9/25/14
,0.7600,66067.3,50212.4,61.0
,49.572,-0.3720,0.0000
,111.89,108.28,94.72,106.23
,99.82,83.41
```

i have tried

```
line = line.replace("REEL SCAN" + "," + "BASIS WT" + "\n\n", "");
```

and other variations of that i found on here, but no luck.
all i need is that second line completely gone, but it wont always be the second line.

Comment: Always use `StringBuilder` unless you have a *very* good reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps just skip that line entirely from the StringBuffer

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.contains("REEL SCAN,BASIS WT") {
        continue;
    }
    stringBuffer.append(line.trim());
    stringBuffer.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: gtgaxiola, you are the man, i feel so dumb for not thinking of it that way. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write the empty line. Only if line.isEmpty() is false.

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replace("REEL SCAN" + "," + "BASIS WT", "");
    if(!line.isEmpty()){
        stringBuffer.append(line.trim());
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This takes care of the case when you have more information other than REEL SCAN,BASIS WT